# How to Publish Docx file with images to WordPress site?

Tags: python, wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

So I am able to post **Docx files to WordPress using WP REST-API** using mammoth docx package in Python
I am able to upload an image to WordPress.

But when there are images in the docx file they are not uploading on the WordPress media section.

Any input on this?

I am using python for this.
Here is the code for **Docx to HTML conversion**

```
        with open(file_path, "rb") as docx_file:
            # html = mammoth.extract_raw_text(docx_file)
            result = mammoth.convert_to_html(docx_file, convert_image=mammoth.images.img_element(convert_image))
            html = result.value  # The generated HTML
```

kindly do note that I am able to see images in the actual published post but they have a weird source image URL & are not appearing in the WordPress media section.
Weird image source URL like
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQECAgMCAgICAgQDAwIDBQQFBQUEBAQFBgcGBQUHBgQEBgkGBwgICAgIBQYJCgkICgcICAj/2wBDAQEBAQICAgQCAgQIBQQFCAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAj/wAARCAUABQADASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQMFAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUGBwMECAkKAgsB/8QAhxAAAQIEBAMEBQYHCAUOFggXAQIDAAQFEQYHEiETMUEIIlFhCRQ & so on

Also Huge thanks to Contributors for the **Python to WordPress** repo

Comment: You are cusing the [custom image handler](https://github.com/mwilliamson/python-mammoth/blob/master/README.md#custom-image-handlers) to convert the images to `base64`, so that's what you're seeing. A better approach would be to extract the images and upload them individually to wordpress.

Comment: I tried to do using that but I have issues in mapping the images into the post :( Have tried using attachment id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mammoth` [cli](https://github.com/mwilliamson/python-mammoth/blob/master/mammoth/cli.py) has a function that extracts images, saves them to a directory and inserts the file names in the `img` tags in the `html` code. If you don't want to use `mammoth` in command line you could use this code:

```
import os
from mammoth.cli import ImageWriter, _write_output

output_dir = './output'
filename = 'filename.docx'

with open(filename, "rb") as docx_fileobj:
    convert_image = mammoth.images.img_element(ImageWriter(output_dir))
    output_filename = "{0}.html".format(os.path.basename(filename).rpartition(".")[0])
    output_path = os.path.join(output_dir, output_filename)
    
    result = mammoth.convert(
        docx_fileobj,
        convert_image=convert_image,
        output_format='html',
    )
    _write_output(output_path, result.value)
```

Note that you would still need to change the `img` links as you'll be uploading the images to Wordpress, but this solves your mapping issue. You might also want to change the [`ImageWriter`](https://github.com/mwilliamson/python-mammoth/blob/master/mammoth/cli.py#L42) class to save the images to something else than `tiff`.

Comment: The string you need is `result.value`. It is already there.